# Changed my motherboard - Do I need to reinstall Windows? Will a repair install work?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, repair-install

I had to change my motherboard on my desktop, now I am able to boot into my OS but things don't quite work the same. For example, any game that I play which utilizes the graphics card runs a lot slower.

My question is that do I have to reinstall my OS? Or will a repair install of Windows do the trick?

The manufacturer of my motherboard is still the same. I am using a different model of a Gigabyte motherboard.

**PC Information:**

```
Current Motherboard: Gigabyte B75M-S

Previous Motherboard: Gigabyte H77M-D3H

GPU: Nvidia GeForce 650 GTX 1 GB

CPU: Core i5-3450 3.10 GHZ
```

Comment: Download and install the drivers for you new motherboard.

Comment: "For example, any game that I play which utilizes the graphics card runs a lot slower." - This sounds like a driver issue and unrelated to reinstall status Windows.

Comment: @Moab which drives should I download? Chipset drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound Then a repair install is not required?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the drivers for your motherboard?  Have you reinstalled the display drivers?  It sounds like the application in question is using the iGPU instead of the dGPU which would explain the performance hit.   Using the Windows 10 Reset functionality is unlikely going to solve the problem you describe, or it might as a side effect, and it is not necessary if you just identify the cause of the performance hit

Comment: @Ramhound no I didn't. My previous motherboard did not require any separate download so since the manufacturer and model is similar I haven't done any download. How do I  "tell" Windows to use my new drivers and stop using the old ones? Any command or way I can do that?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer a lot of your questions.  You failed to identify the motherboard.  You failed to identify which version of Windows you are using. You failed to identify your CPU and GPU.  You also only asked, if reinstalling Windows is required when you change the motherboard, but the answer to that question is "it depends".  **You have not provided enough information to determine if it's required in your specific case.**  Before you do anything install the drivers appropriate for your motherboard.  After you do that, edit your question, and include the info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89488/discussion-between-ramhound-and-ng-newbie).

Comment: @ng.newbie download and install All the available drivers for that motherboard.